# Can someone provide me some guidance with OpenLog in Java?

Tags: java, xpages

In an application I want to include OpenLog but I have some questions regarding the implementation.

```
if (db.isOpen()){
  //perform action
}else{
  OpenLogUtil.logError(session, null, Utils.getSession().getEffectiveUserName() + " has unsufficient access for database: " + sourceDB.getFileName(), ?? , null);
}
```

I am not sure how I should provide the severity level.

Can someone explain this to me with a code example?

Comment: I can be off-topic, but have you considered using slf4j instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you import java.util.logging.Level you can then use Level.INFO, Level.WARNING, etc. as the severity levels.